# Handling change event on extjs checkboxgroup

Tags: extjs

I am very much confused on handling change in checkboxgroup.
I want to get an array which consists all the newvalues of checkboxes.
The final array will have the id of the chekbox and its corresponding values whether checked or not.

I have this checkboxgroup as dynamic.

```
var checkboxconfigs = [];
checkboxconfigs.push({ //pushing into array
               id:record.data.SubTickets[z].Id,
               boxLabel:record.data.SubTickets[z].Name,
               status:record.data.SubTickets[z].Status
 });

 xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                            fieldLabel: 'Checklist',
                            columns: 1,
                            vertical: true,
                            listeners: {

                                change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts)
                                {    
                                }                                
                            },
                            items: checkboxconfigs
```

The next thing I need is to get an array with all new values and their respective id.
May be like a key value pair array , so that I can pass this array to function.
How do I create this array here also after creation of I want to call the function.

Comment: I set `name` and `inputValue` on the checkboxes, and that works.

Comment: @Alexander thanks! but my concern is something else.I want to create an array ex:[{'123':'on'},{'456':''}] , these are the newvalues of array.Also I would need to pass the array to a function but dont know where can I call the function from.

Comment: I want to pass function after change event.In change event the array will be created and then after change I want to call function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not perfect coded, but you can use this as example

```
myCheckboxGroup.on({
    change: function(checkboxGroup, newValue) {
        var formattedValues = [];

        // myGroup is your checkboxes `name` property
        newValue = newValue.myGroup.length === 0 ? [newValue.myGroup] : newValue.myGroup;

        checkboxGroup.items.each(function(checkbox){
            var checkboxValue = checkbox.inputValue,
                foramttedValue = {};

            foramttedValue[checkboxValue] = newValue.indexOf(checkboxValue) !== -1 ? 'on' : 'off';

            formattedValues.push(foramttedValue);
        });

        console.log(formattedValues);
    }
});
```

`formattedValues` in JSON look like this

```
[{"field1":"off"},{"field2":"on"},{"field3":"off"},{"field4":"on"},{"field5":"off"}]
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/153l)

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot!

Comment: Accepted , cant upvote Stackoverflow not allowing me to do.